# Postgresql - Error Connection terminated due to connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpc, node-postgres

I have created a google cloud function in google cloud which will connect to my postgresql instance created in Google cloud.

I am using 'pg' node module.

I have create a private IP for this.

I am getting following error:

> Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout at
> Timeout.connectionTimeoutHandle.setTimeout
> (/workspace/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:106:28) at ontimeout
> (timers.js:436:11) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5) at listOnTimeout
> (timers.js:263:5) at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)

when trying to query the database in google cloud.

This is my configuration which I am using in google cloud function.

> {
> "host": "",
> "user": "",
> "pw": "",
> "db": "<database_name>",
> "port": "5432",
> "table": "<table_name",
> "max": 100,
> "idleTimeoutMillis": 30000,
> "connectionTimeoutMillis": 30000 }

Please help me with this

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading pg npm version resolved the issue.

```
"pg": "^7.3.0",
```

to

```
"pg": "^8.7.1",
```

If the issue still persists, then check your node version. Upgrade node to >=14.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation:

[Connecting from Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#private-ip)

> To connect directly with private IP, you need to:
>
> 1.Make sure that the Cloud SQL instance created above has a private IP
> address. If you need to add one, see the Configuring private IP page
> for instructions.
>
> 2.Create a Serverless VPC Access connector in the same
> VPC network as your Cloud SQL instance. Unless you're using Shared
> VPC, a connector must be in the same project and region as the
> resource that uses it, but the connector can send traffic to resources
> in different regions.
>
> 3.Configure Cloud Functions to use the connector. Connect using your
> instance's private IP and port 5432.
>
> 4.Connect using your instance's private IP and port 5432

Also you can find the node js code to establish the connection to database:

```
const connectWithTcp = config => {
  // Extract host and port from socket address
  const dbSocketAddr = process.env.DB_HOST.split(':'); // e.g. '127.0.0.1:5432'

  // Establish a connection to the database
  return Knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      user: process.env.DB_USER, // e.g. 'my-user'
      password: process.env.DB_PASS, // e.g. 'my-user-password'
      database: process.env.DB_NAME, // e.g. 'my-database'
      host: dbSocketAddr[0], // e.g. '127.0.0.1'
      port: dbSocketAddr[1], // e.g. '5432'
    },
    // ... Specify additional properties here.
    ...config,
  });
};
```